# Crash while swapping child VC using ViewController Containment

Tags: ios, ios5

I'm running into a problem that I'm hoping someone here can help with.

I'm writing an app that includes ViewController containment.  The main controller swaps the various child controllers in and out as the user manipulates a SegmentedController.

It seems to work correctly, but I've found a vulnerability.  If I select segments TOO QUICKLY, I can get the app to crash with the following error:

**2012-01-19 04:29:39.539 MyApp[1057:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Children view controllers (ChildViewController1): 0x6e91480 and ChildViewController1: 0x6e8dca0 must have a common parent view controller when calling -[UIViewController transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:]'**

It SEEMS that the issue is that I'm triggering an action while my animation is running (and the child controllers are being swapped in and out), and that that's the problem, but I'm not exactly sure how to PROTECT the UI from doing this while the animation is running.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Here's the code that's running the VC swap:

```
- (IBAction)selectPage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Page Selected");   
    UIViewController *newViewController = [[self patientChartViewControllers] objectAtIndex:[sender selectedSegmentIndex]];
    [self addChildViewController:newViewController];
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:[newViewController title]];
    [self transitionFromViewController:[self currentPatientChartViewController] toViewController:newViewController duration:0.50 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve 
        animations:^{
            [[[self currentPatientChartViewController] view] removeFromSuperview]; 
            newViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds; 
            [[self view] addSubview:[newViewController view]];
        } 
        completion:^(BOOL finished){ 
            [newViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self]; 
            [[self currentPatientChartViewController] removeFromParentViewController]; 
            [self setCurrentPatientChartViewController:newViewController];
        }];
```

}

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the exact same issue (iOS 7.1.1) and disabling the segmented control while the animation runs doesn't help me either.

Comment: possible duplicate of [App crashes if view controller transition is done too quickly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18830837/app-crashes-if-view-controller-transition-is-done-too-quickly)

Answer (score 3):

I am not quite sure, but I think the transition among view controllers is handled by `Core Animation` framework and for some reason, `Core Animation` doesn't like doing multiple things while interacting with user -- all the same time.

To prevent this from happening, my understading is that, your SegmentedController (presumably an instance of `UISegmentControl`) stays in the view, while views are being exchanged. For the time that view are being exchanged, you can disable the user interaction of `SegmentController` so that users can not switch views-- they have to wait for the complete transition of view A to B.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Canopus,  I had tried disabling the SegmentController with no success (the same crash still occurred), but I agree with you that this is probably connected to user interaction while CA is trying to do the animation.  I'll keep searching, but thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using `transitionFromViewController:toViewController:duration:options:animations:completion:` with the flag check using **completion** block, but it seems completion block finishes before the animation, even if I set **duration** to 0.

If user is changing child view controller really fast, I think we should add and remove child view controller ourself, so as to avoid the animation. This works for me

Something like this

```
// Removing currentVC
[currentVC willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[currentVC.view removeFromSuperview];
[currentVC removeFromParentViewController];

// Adding nextVC
[self addChildViewController:nextVC];
nextVC.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:nextVC.view];
[nextVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
self.currentVC = nextVC
```